# PAX-CDI change log level

Tags: osgi, cdi, pax

I am using pax-cdi and when I start it I get hundreds lines of information - what package is scanned, qualifiers etc. How to disable outputting this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting the right log level in your logger. If your using pax exam add the required logback or pax - logging bundles to your environment. 
If used in plain OSGi make sure you have a log framework installed. I would suggest pax - logging it's proven to work.

**EDIT:**
Add the following dependencies to your setup:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>pax-logging-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>pax-logging-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

set the logging by either using configuration Admin service, 
or add the following while starting your application:

```
-Dorg.ops4j.pax.logging.DefaultServiceLog.level=WARN
```

More information can be found at the [documentation](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxlogging/) of Pax-Logging

Comment: Could you say more exactly what I should do. I am not very good in logging.

Comment: What's your scenario, Pax-Exam or just an osgi application? With such a general question you just get a general answer.

Comment: I use pax-cdi+weld+felix , generally it's usual osgi application with cdi.